# How to copy text from a buffer to an ansi-term

Tags: window, ansi-term

If I create a second window with a terminal in it like:

`C-x 2; C-x o; M-x ansi-term`

How can I copy text from a buffer into this terminal? I seems like the ansi-terminal has its own kill-ring (maybe the killring from readline?)

Context: I use a REPL quite often for development, sometimes it's on a remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

From the doc for `term-mode`:

> The terminal emulator uses Term mode, which has two input modes. In line mode, Term basically acts like Shell mode. In char mode, each character is sent directly to the subshell, except for the Term escape character, normally C-c.
>
> C-c C-c send a literal C-c to the sub-shell.

From the doc for `shell-mode`:

> The major mode for Shell buffers is Shell mode. Many of its special commands are bound to the C-c prefix, and resemble the usual editing and job control characters present in ordinary shells, except that you must type C-c first.

Into `ansi-term` use `C-x C-j` to switch terminal into line mode.  In this mode you could use `C-y` to insert content from the emacs kill ring.  Switching back to character mode could be done with `C-c C-k`.

This happens because `ansi-term` mode runs custom terminal (like `/bin/bash`), which have its own function for keys `C-k`, `C-y`, etc. This keys works with kill ring similar to emacs kill ring but into `bash`.  So, if you kill string into char mode (in `bash`) and then try to paste it, the string will be pasted, but the kill ring will be `bash` kill ring.

This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886184/copy-paste-in-emacs-ansi-term-shell

Answer (score 2):

I used these functions for that

```el
;; yank in term (kill-ing)
(defun term-yank-kill-ring ()
  (interactive)
  (flet ((insert-for-yank (string) (term-send-raw-string string)))
    (yank)))
;; yank-pop un term (kill-ring)
(defun term-yank-pop-kill-ring ()
  (interactive)
  (dotimes (i (- (point) (mark t)))
    (term-send-backspace))
  (process-send-string
   (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))
   (current-kill 1)))
;; shorcuts
(setq term-bind-key-alist
      '(("C-x C-y" . term-yank-kill-ring)
        ("C-x M-y" . term-yank-pop-kill-ring)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I switch to evil-mode by pressing `C-z`. Then use vim key bindings to copy/paste text.

That's also my preferred way to run other REPL (js-comint, mostly).